# SP13: Overwriting Excel Importing List

Tags: custom-list, excel

This task seems easy, but is turning out to be more complex than I expected. I have a excel spreadsheet that I have imported into a custom list.  In order to import the excel spreadsheet by using "Import Excel Spreadsheet" app. My objective is to import a new excel spreadsheet but overwrite the existing custom list.  Is there a way to do this without having to delete every item in the custom list and trying to import a new list (if possible)?

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the import spreadsheet functionality only works to create new lists, not add to existing ones.

You could, however, use Microsoft Access.  With Access you can connect to the list and then copy/paste (or use one of the other many features of Access) to import the data into the list.